# What is the male equivalent of an alice band?

Tags: single-word-requests

An "alice band" is so named, after the one worn by [Alice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alice_%28Alice%27s_Adventures_in_Wonderland%29) in Lewis Carroll's stories.

Is there a male equivalent, to describe those worn by men with long hair (e.g. David Beckham)?

[image: David Beckham]

Comment: Is *alice band* a UK thing? I've only ever heard them called hairbands and headbands in the US.

Comment: Oh! Particularly for sports, I also hear them called sweatbands. That might be the most masculine alternative.

Comment: A sweatband is something different. It is for soaking up sweat. An alice band is for keeping your hair in place.

Comment: Ah okay. Headband/hairband, then.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No; it's still called an alice band, or sometimes the gender-neutral *hairband* or *headband*. They might also be referred to as *sport(s) bands* but that term is slightly misleading as it could equally apply to a wristband or similar.

I wouldn't be surprised to see the tabloid press coin a term like "Beckham-band", but there's not a common male equivalent in widespread use.

Comment: FWIW, you can see (29.08.2013) an [article from the Guardian on Gareth Bale](http://www.theguardian.com/football/blog/2013/aug/28/gareth-bale-tottenham-real-madrid) using "alice band" in context.